# Jquery : How to trigger a click event when input focus is enable

Tags: jquery

I have an input field. On its focusin event I am opening a tooltip and on its focuout I am closing the tooltip. But now I am having a link on tooltip and what I want to do to make that link clickable. 
But when I start focusing input and go to that tooltip link and try to click than the input's focusout event gets called first and the tooltip gets closed. So I was unable to click that link.
Here is my code :

html:

```
<div class="block"><input type="text" class="field-input"/><div class="tooltip">
<a href="#">tooltip link</a></div>
```

css:

```
.block{position:relative;}.tooltip{position:absolute;right:0;display:none;bottom:0;}
```

jquery:

```
$('.field-input').on('focusin', function(){
$('tooltip').show();
});
$('.field-input').on('focusout', function(){
    $('tooltip').hide();
});
$('.tooltip a').on('click', function(){
    ... do something
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the focusout event binding when the mouse enters the tooltip and add it back when the mouse leaves:

```
$('.tooltip').on({
  mouseenter: function(){
    $('.field-input').off('focusout');
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $('.field-input').on('focusout', function(){
      $('.tooltip').hide();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I never had an idea that it would be really simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) to capture the element that is receiving the focus, and hide tooltip only if the clicked element is **not** the tooltip anchor.

From the docs:

> The **MouseEvent.relatedTarget** read-only property is the secondary
>   target for the event, if there is one. That is:
>
> **focusout**: *The EventTarget receiving focus*

Something like that:

```
$('.field-input').on('focusout', function(e){
    var tooltipHolder = $('.tooltip');
    var tooltipAnchor = tooltipHolder.find('a');
    if (e.relatedTarget !== tooltipAnchor[0]) tooltipHolder.hide();
});
```